# IIS, TLS and SSL Version Or SSL HttpWebRequest in C# "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: ssl

It was several things, the other server (A Webmethods Integration Server) is a little picky about what kinds of protocols it accepts. So after some fiddling around here are the two things that fixed it:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

and

```
req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
```

So the whole code is:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

**//for TLS Version as set TLSv1.2**

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://websiteURL:9000");

//Header Settings

req.Method = "POST"; // Post method

req.ContentType = "text/xml";// content type

req.KeepAlive = false;

req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

//Certificate with private key

X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("Cert.der","Password");

req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

req.PreAuthenticate = true;

String XML = "Test Message"//reader.ReadToEnd();

byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XML);

req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

// Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer

Stream writer = req.GetRequestStream();

// Write the XML text into the stream

writer.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

writer.Close();

WebResponse rsp = req.GetResponse();

StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

**//for TLS Version as set TLSv1.2 call before service call**

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;